# 4 SSDs RAID 0 integreted vs dedicated controller

Tags: performance, ssd, raid, sata

I've been thinking about setting up 4 SSD RAID 0 to gain performance in my home PC, and I ran into [this review](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/ocz_revodrive_350_pcie_ssd_review,1.html) of PCI-E based SSD.

If I use [PERC H310](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/Documents/dell-perc-h310-spec-sheet.pdf) (8 lane PCI-E 2.0 RAID controller, which means theoretical maximum of 4000MB/s) and 4 60GB SSDs it's still half price of that PCI-E SSD.

Since It's basically a RAID controller with separate SSDs on board, in theory it is possible to reach similar speeds with 4 x 60GB 400MB/s capable SSDs in RAID 0 configuration.

Is there any real benefit in using PERC H310 instead of AMD integrated SATA controller, I'm talking high-end chipsets like A88X and 990FX ?

I know the answer in theory, but does anyone have any real world experience with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any SATA RAID controller out there that will provide you with the speed which you anticipate from 4 SSDs in RAID 0

I highly recommend watching this video for an excellent explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27GmBzQWwP0

Basically, SATA-bound SSDs in RAID 0 still have to go through some sort of bridge either on the Motherboard or the dedicated RAID controller and that bridge has a maximum throughput which is usually reached rather easily.

Using PCI-e SSDs in RAID 0 will produce nearly boundless speeds.

Comment: After some more research, and as shown in the video above, I'm gonna go with 3xSSD as the fourth one doesn't increase the speed that much, and having 3 means less chanse of failure.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić Have you done it? Did you use PCIe ?

Comment: @Pedro77 No, I didn't go for PCIe, but I did try with 2xSSD first. I could hit roughly R:850 W:700 MB/s but to be honest I didn't see any huge real-world performance increase. I did try to add a third one but it didn't run well as I had some freezing issues. Anyway – not the best option, you are probably better off with one larger SSD or going with NVMe.